# Android- Listview- Buttons

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a Listview with add button when i click add new row of buttons
created dynamically. When i scroll listview these new buttons are
visible. How can i click add buttons then the  buttons are immediately
visible. Why it is happened. There is any way to handle this issue.

I've try `invalidateViews()` `invalidate()` it doesn't work. Please help me to solve this .
My sample code here 
a

```
dd_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button =  new Button(getApplicationContext());
        linear.addView(button1, lparams);
        listview.invalidateViews();                                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your listview is not refreshing.

Comment: yes how can i refresh listview.

Comment: You need to add a row of buttons to your ListAdapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). The view itself will be created by Adapter and ListView will be updated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve my issue like this. Call this method

```
//Here running boolean value
//lv listview

    private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
            lv.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!running) {

                 // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                    iv.setSelection(daily_dairy_2.getCount() - 1);
                    lv.invalidateViews();
                    running = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To refresh a Listview, create a ListAdapter and populate it with your items (buttons). Every time you put in it a new set of items, your list gets updated.

Check this reference on ListViews: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use listview.notifyDatasetChanged() method to refresh your list.